# Hosted React app track clicks with uniques session without user interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, logging, tracking

I know not exactly how to ask this appropriately and where. I tried searching around and visited various (paid) solutions, but I would require a simple solution.
For a scientific work of mine I want to track user interactions or basically button clicks on a simple **React** site like this example I made http://flock-1401.students.fhstp.ac.at/

Assume the user visits the provided link above, then I want to create a log on a server (maybe nodejs self-hosted) where the user's interaction is tracked with a unique session to distinguish them. At most, there will be 150 users active.

I tried to use the following library:
https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga

However, I tend to not use Google Analytics as I don't need all the included stuff there. Maybe something like this https://github.com/greenstick/interactor? But how do I automatically save it then?

Thank you